# How to display xyz.com website content in abc.com website with same url paths except domain name?

Tags: networking, uri, web-hosting

Let's say I have a domain name called ABC.com and also I have another domain called XYZ.com. Now here I have the content in ABC.com website and the challenge is I want to access the same content in my another domain named as(XYZ.com) with the same path except domain name.

EX: abc.com/somepage.html or abc.com/somefolder/otherpage.html

Now I need to get the same content from abc.com to xyz.com with same paths......

EX: xyz.com/somepage.html or xyz.com/somefolder/otherpage.html

I heard about this by adding CNAME Records in another domain and can access it.

Comment: Just point the new domain to the same server and add it as an alias in your vhost. How to do that depends on what web server you're running etc.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what php, jquery, html, angular have to do with your question. You should only include tags that's directly relevant to your issue.

Comment: Is all the content the same or only some of the content of the site?

Comment: all the content will be the same only domain name should be different. If I want to say clearly it's like cloning

Comment: I am using GoDaddy server and if u have any reference pages regarding custom domain can u share me the link? - @Magnus Eriksson

Comment: Sorry, I'm no GoDaddy-expert. Just contact them and ask how to do it.